# Find $Df_{(x,y,z)}$ for $f(x,y,z)=xy-z^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find $Df_{(x,y,z)}$ for
$$f:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R},~~f(x,y,z)=xy-z^2.$$

For example, for $f(x,y,z)=x+2y-z,$ we have $Df_{(x,y,z)}=[1,2,-1]$, a $3\times 1$ matrix. But for the case $f(x,y,z)=xy-z^2,$ I don't know what's the $Df_{(x,y,z)}.$ Anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: The entries of your matrix will always be the derivatives taken with respect to each variable in turn. It makes no difference whether $x$, $y$, and $z$ are grouped into separate terms.

Answer (score 0):

$Df$ is again going to be a $1\times 3$ matrix.  Just compute

$$
Df_{(x,y,z)} \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_xf & \partial_yf & \partial_z f\\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be a $1\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: And in this case, $Df(x,y,z)=[y,x,-2z]$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess a rule from an example is in general either difficult or impossible. I suggest you ask yourself first what the definition of $Df$ is. As the comment by Stan Corey Carter suggests, it is a matrix of partial derivatives. In your case, a matrix that maps $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, a $1\times 3$ matrix. In the general case, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$,
$Df$ is the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{df_1}{dx_1}&\frac{df_1}{dx_2}&...&\frac{df_1}{dx_n}\\
\frac{df_2}{dx_1}&\frac{df_2}{dx_2}&...&\frac{df_2}{dx_n}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{df_m}{dx_1}&\frac{df_m}{dx_2}&...&\frac{df_m}{dx_n}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In your case, you need
$$
Df(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{df}{dx}(x,y,z),&\frac{df}{dy}(x,y,z),&\frac{df}{dz}(x,y,z)
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where each entry is to be understood as a partial derivative of $f$, evaluated at the point $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: So in this case, $Df(x,y,z)=[y,x,-2z],$ a $1\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's right.